# Task scheduling using cron expression from properties file

Tags: cron

I have written a cron job:

```
@Scheduled(cron="${process.virtual.account.start}")
public void ecomProcessVirAccOrderPaymentsScheduler() {
    LOGGER.info("Start --->" + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ".ecomProcessVirAccOrderPaymentsScheduler() Method");
    schedulerJobHelper.ecomProcessVirAccOrderPaymentsScheduler();
    LOGGER.info("End --->" + this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ".ecomProcessVirAccOrderPaymentsScheduler() Method");
}
```

I want to get the cron attribute used with `@Scheduled` annotation to be populated from a external properties file. Currently I am fetching it from a property file inside the application scope.
I am able to fetch the value, but not able to use it with `@Schedule` annotation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Which version of spring framework are you using? This won't work if it is less than 3.0.1.

[Bug Report here in Spring 3.0.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6670) and it has been fixed in 3.0.1.

So if you are using Spring 3.0.1 or greater then following things you have to do to use in cron expression

Make an entry in applicationContext.xml for PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer class that is

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ApplicationProps.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After That  Use it in using the @Scheduled method like

> **Update:** In case if you are using **spring boot** no need to do anything, below code excerpt should work.

```
@Scheduled(cron="${instructionSchedularTime}")
public void load(){
}
```

Note: fixed delay and fixed-rate cann't take property value from placeholder because they take long value. Cron attribute take argument as String so you can use placeholder for that.

Comment: As of Spring 3.2.2 you now have: [fixedDelayString](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelayString--) and [fixedRateString](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedRateString--) as well.

Answer (score 45):

it is working in spring boot.

```
@Scheduled(cron="${cronExpression}")
private void testSchedule()  {
    System.out.println("Helloooo");
}
```

in `application.properties` I have a property like this as below:

```
cronExpression=* * * ? * *
```

Comment: In which version of spring boot?

Comment: @NeeruKSingh I have tested it in the latest spring boot version V2.5.2 and it is working

Comment: I've tested. This solution is working. Spring v 2.6.2

Answer (score 4):

You can assign value directly from property file, i'm using spring boot BTW

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${com.oracle.fusion.cron}")
public void getInvoiceInterfaceHeader() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/path/to/file")
public class LoadPropertiesFile{
   //Other project configurations
}
```

For more, [click](https://javapapers.com/spring/spring-properties-with-propertysource-annotation/) here

Answer (score 0):

For me works in that way:

```
"#{${cronExpression}}
```

Comment: Very curious as to that syntax and as I am sure others would be benefited by it could you break down the "what/why"?

Comment: This gives error: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [* 1 * * * *] @0: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand